# Design approach for error handling in rest based components

Tags: java, rest, osgi

I've 3 components A,B and C

A= End-users
B= A middleware which takes input from end-user A and delegates the request it to C
C= Does some work and returns response to B.

Use Case: Let's say that after delegating the request successfully from B to C, the C component goes down. What would be the most appropriate approach in terms of error-handling?

Should I add a time-out functionality on B component so that if B doesn't get a response from C for a specified period of time, then it's going to return an error response?

In order to keep a track of the request that have failed, should I make use of Database storage or persistent queue to log down the error responses?

Kindly advise.

Comment: Nice question. flagged with moderator.It is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should ask yourself about the usage of some framework:

- http://spring.io/
- http://www.takes.org/
- something else.

If you want to realize low-level logic yourself, you definitely look over already existed realizations and their parameters for timeouts (like this http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-timeout).

And you also should better return an error code from C to B in case of something went wrong (that mean you should catch all exceptions on C side and wrap them into error response). I even want to say that it's better to return a negative result in case of error instead of throwing exceptions (it will cost less) and throw only unchecked exceptions (https://blog.philipphauer.de/checked-exceptions-are-evil/ - if you ask why).